# Can you copy files to /Applications using Launchbar?

Tags: macos, mac, launchbar

For lot of applications, the disc image (.dmg) contains the .app files which needs to be copied to the /Applications folder.

I use Launchbar's Instant Send feature to open the selected files quickly in some text editor. Is there a way I can use this feature to quickly send a selected application to /Applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you use the Instant Send hotkey to select the file in Launchbar...

[image: Launchbar screenshot]

You can start typing "Applications" to select your `/Applications` folder.

[image: Launchbar screenshot]

Then press <kbd>Return</kbd> and select *Copy to "Applications"* from the menu.

[image]